# Проверка авторизации React JS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

Делаю приложение на react js 
Есть авторизация и доступ к сайту после нее. 
Сделал проверку авторизовался пользователь или нет при отрисовке дефолтного шаблона. На сколько это правильно?

[image: Проверка авторизации]

Comment: Ну вроде так все делают, только я чаще видел вариант, где в самом роуте в методе render пишут такую функцию, чтоб не гадать что будет отрендеренно.

Comment: Я в render вставил return {this.checkAuth()}